# Export Complete Wave Dashboard as PDF with Visualforce/Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, pdf, analytics

Is it possible to get the Wave dashboard as a PDF document or in the mail as an attachment programmatically with either a VF page or Lightning? I have tried the VF page code to get it as a pdf option but it cuts off the dashboard from the sides and the colors are not visible properly. Also tried many more ways with VF but the pdf is appearing blank. The dashboard is coming properly via the VF page but when we use renderAs PDF it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The dashboard depends on JavaScript technology, which can't run or render in a PDF.